# Is the Bruhat cell Zariski open in a connected algebraic group $G$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

Is the Bruhat cell Zariski-open in a connected algebraic group $G$?
Specifically, is the big Bruhat cell Zariski-open (and maybe Zariski-dense)?

Is it true for all the Bruhat cells?

Comment: The top dimensional Bruhat cell is Zarisli open and dense; and, of course, all the others cells are not. You will find this in any book on algebraic groups, e.g. *Linear Algebraic Groups* by A. Borel.

Comment: Zariski open implies Zariski dense in a connected algebraic group.